# Testing user password expiration with openldap

Tags: ldap, openldap

I need to test whether our application can handle a user needing to change their password. I'm using the Docker openldap server available from here: https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap.

I've added various things from here https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Password%20MUST%20Change to my schema, however if I try to add pwdMustChange to a user, Apache Directory Studio will fail saying the schema doesn't allow for it.

This is what I've put in my schema:

```
attributetype ( PwdMustChange
NAME 'PwdMustChange'
DESC 'Password Must Be Changed'
EQUALITY booleanMatch
SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.7
)
```

Apache Directory Studio recognises the value as it autofills pwdMustChange, but when I try to enter a value in the above error occurs.

My question boils down to: How can I simulate a user password expiration with openldap?

Comment: You can't just add arbitrary attributes to objects in LDAP. You need to enable and configure the password policy feature, and use it correctty.

Comment: Would you mind pointing me to a resource explaining how to do so?

Comment: Yes, http://openldap.org.

Answer (score 1):

Which programming language and which LDAP module for this are you using?

I'd suggest to do a bit more of reading:

- [OpenLDAP 2.4 Admin Guide -- Configuring slapd](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html) because the Docker image you're using insists on using OpenLDAP's dynamic configuration backend
- [OpenLDAP 2.4 Admin Guide -- Password Policies](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html#Password%20Policies)
- [slapo-ppolicy(5)](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-ppolicy) describes the meaning of all attributes in the pwdPolicy entry
- OpenLDAP implements this draft version: [draft-behera-ldap-password-policy-09](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-behera-ldap-password-policy-09)